# Facebook V4.0.0 share Image issue

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to utilize Facebook V4.0.0 SDK for Image sharing.

I am using `SharePhoto` and `SharePhotoContent` class to share image over facebook.

Please check code below

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " text 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).setUserGenerated(true).build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(sharePhoto).build();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " text 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    shareDialog.show(content);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " text 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I am able to share Video over facebook using inline code successfully.

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
    ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(selectedVideo).build();
    ShareVideoContent shareVideoContent = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(shareVideo)
        .setContentTitle(StaticCredentials.HASH_TAG)
        .setContentDescription(StaticCredentials.HASH_TAG)
        .build();
    shareDialog.show(shareVideoContent);
}
```

Getting error `Failed to copy image` while sharing Image.

Looking to have any suggestions over this.

Thanks for your kind concern and support.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Dear, May be this doc helps you to solve the Issue for that https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Thanks Rajan for your kind concern. IM utilizing same. May you please get me some other way to check this out. Thanks

Comment: Did you add the content provider as per the doc?

Comment: Yes... Every stuff is working great. I don't know why code was not acting properly. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack trace?

Comment: Thanks sleepy for your kind concern. There's was some minute error in my flow. Facebook sharing is working great.! :)

Comment: @AndroidHacker  hey can you please tell me what was the error because i am also suffer from the same problem, here not able to post the video although done the same code as above as well as fb guide. help would be appriciated

Comment: @Concentrated_Attitude  Please do check your manifest file settings... There you need  to mention some of meta-data stuff with project ID. Make sure that your App ID mentioned in your string.xml file and  meta deta is correct ...You just need to follow one step by another mentioned in doc ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: @AndroidHacker all the things are already set the correctly i also post the image using shared dialog but unable post the video issue is that there is nothing happen while trying to open video dialog.
if you could post the code for share video then it would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to post a video please do inline stuff ..

```
private void shareOverFacebookVideo(Uri selectedVideo) {
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
            ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(selectedVideo).build();
            ShareVideoContent shareVideoContent = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                    .setVideo(shareVideo)
                    .setRef(party_key1)
                    .setContentTitle(party_key1)
                    .setContentDescription(party_key1)
                    .build();
            shareDialog.show(shareVideoContent);
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can't show pic upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Call method like : `shareOverFacebookVideo(uri);`

Pick video like ...

```
public void getVideo(final int requestcode) {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Video Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("Upload video via");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        pickPhoto.setType("video/*");
                        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, requestcode);//Here requestcode is one that needs to be used over onActivityResult method

                    }
                });

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(takePicture, requestcode);
                    }
                });
        myAlertDialog.show();

    }
```

Let me know if any concern in same.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The following works precisely. This is in reference to the original question regarding "SharePhoto and SharePhotoContent":

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.your_image_here);

SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();

SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(sharePhoto).build();

ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);

shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
```

Here is a related comment and point of interest...

@AndroidHacker or anyone familiar with the video part of this question above:
*** Have you been able to use the method ShareVideoContent.setContentTitle successfully?
No matter what I try and using this exact code (which is straight from within the SDK documentation), I have not been able to get the ShareVideoContent.setContentTitle method from the Android SDK to work (and thus be seen in the Timeline / News Feed).
I've been able to do this in PHP and it works perfectly, so you know it can be done - but from the Android SDK it is not working...
Thank You So Much!!